# iphone - custom font costs extra memory?

Tags: iphone, uilabel, custom-font

I need to use an external custom font for my UILabel. I managed to do it and it is working.

I have totally like 50 UILabel in my app. Each UILabel has the same custom font that I embed with my app.

All 50 UILabels are loaded at one time into the memory.

**Each** UILabel's text is around 200 bytes of NSStrings, the sum of all texts are around 1K - 2K bytes. I made a mistake previously by writing each UILabel's text is 1K - 2K, sorry.

I noticed one thing, if I apply the custom font to the UILabels, the memory costs very high, like 30 - 40MB extra more than without custom fonts.

Is this possible?

My app is very simple currently just show 5 pages, each page has 10 UILabels. So no other places or bugs would exist, I think

Comment: As Joe says, that's a lot of text to be displaying in UILabels. But how are you applying fonts in the first place? I'd post some code showing how you're doing it, there might be a memory issue there.

Comment: I think there is no code for that. I just include the custom font file into my project and set it up in info.plist

Comment: ...so your labels are in IB? Otherwise you'd be creating `UIFont` objects and assigning them to your labels.

Comment: NO, I create my labels manually, not from IB. and yes, you are right, i have a global UIFont (static) and assign that UIFont to each UILabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the labels have 1k - 2k worth of text I am sure that 50 of them can not be displayed all at once. The approach to take here is similar to how the UITableView works, as the user scrolls, switch tabs, etc then only display labels that will be visible to the user and unload the others. This will reduce the memory peak and you will only need to have the custom fonts loaded for the displayed labels.

Comment: hi, thanks. Even if I only show 10 a time (40 other UILabels in memory but hidden), still can't hold 50 in memory? And you mean each UILabel will cost extra memory if its font is custom?

Comment: I would assume the font would only needed to be loaded once and shared between labels but I am not positive on that. You could create a bare bones project with a system font and a few labels and monitor in instruments and then add your custom font and see how much it changes.